# Pasting Special based on filter range Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

**Goal:** My range is all rows for which Parish has an AICOW "true" value, then in Column C, at the next empty row, I would like to paste, for the range, special text "Business Interruption".

**Code:** My code however is getting error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error. I am not sure how I am meant to edit this to make my goal work.

```
Dim RPDataTbl As ListObject
Dim ParishCol As ListColumn, AICOW As ListColumn
Dim SpecialText As Range

Set RPDataTbl = Sheets("Risk Partner Data").ListObjects("RPdata")
With RPDataTbl
    Set ParishCol = .ListColumns("Parish")
    Set AICOWcol = .ListColumns("AICOW")

    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=AICOWcol.Index, Criteria1:="TRUE"
End With

On Error Resume Next
Set SpecialText = ParishCol.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not SpecialText Is Nothing Then

    With Sheets("Calc Data")
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Format:="Business Interruption"
    End With


End If

RPDataTbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=AICOWcol.Index
```

End Sub

Thank for the assist.

Comment: Try: .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "Business Interruption"

Comment: On which line are you getting error?

Comment: I am getting the error on the .Cells(.Rows.Count,"C")...etcetc.

Comment: @Variatus I have tried, in copies it only for the first empty cell but not for the whole range unfortunately.

Comment: Try: SpecialText.Copy .Cells(...

Comment: Failure to copy is unrelated to the error you asked about. Your code is incomplete. It assigns the range SpecialText but doesn't copy its value, nor pastes its value elsewhere.

Comment: I dont want to copy the range, I want to paste special text for the range i.e. the range gives me how many rows will apply (this variable could change) and based on the range say 10, this formula is to paste into C at next empty "Business Interruption" for the next 10 rows.